# evento com scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, css, rolamento, javascript-eventos, css-animations

Tenho o código abaixo criando o efeito de fadein e fadeout com a biblioteca animate.css em um evento do scroll, porém quando o evento ocorre aplicando o fadeOut, ele reaparece até que mexa no scroll, e o outro erro é que enquanto o scroll for menor que 28, ele fica fazendo e repetindo o efeito FadeIn, e quero que só ocorra o fadeIn se o FadeOut ja tiver sido feito!

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){ 
   
  var animacao1 = "animated fadeOutUp";
  var animacao2 = "animated fadeInDown";
  var fimanimacao = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";
   
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {
   $("#cabecalho .logo").addClass(animacao1);
  }
  if (window.scrollY < 50) {
   $("#cabecalho .logo").removeClass(animacao1);
   $("#cabecalho .logo").addClass(animacao2).one(fimanimacao, function(){
    $(this).removeClass(animacao2);
   });
  }
  });
```

```css
#cabecalho {
   height: 270px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 180px;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #cabecalho .logo {
   height: 37px;
   width: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
   top: 10%
  }
    #altura{
    height: 1400px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="cabecalho">
  <img class="logo" alt="Nome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/SEGA_logo.png">
</div>

<div id="altura"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exitem erros no seu código:**

> **1º** - Não sei onde você arranjou este link para a biblioteca, mas aqui não funcionou. Utilizei esta outra [aqui](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/animate.css/).
>
> **2º** - Você tem que carregar primeiro os **CSS** depois os **JS**, a ordem no seu código está invertida.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){ 
   
   var animacao1 = "animated fadeOutUp";
   var animacao2 = "animated fadeInDown";
   var fimanimacao = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";
   
   if (window.scrollY > 50) {
       $("#cabecalho .logo").addClass(animacao1);
   }
   else if (window.scrollY < 50) {
       $("#cabecalho .logo").removeClass(animacao1);
       $("#cabecalho .logo").addClass(animacao2).one(fimanimacao, function(){
          $(this).removeClass(animacao2);
       });
   }
});
```

```css
#cabecalho {
  height: 270px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 180px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#cabecalho .logo {
  height: 37px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 10%
}
#altura{
   height: 1400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cabecalho">
  <img class="logo" alt="Nome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/SEGA_logo.png">
</div>

<div id="altura"></div>
```

Comment: realmente, na verdade o erro do css foi na hora de publicar, porém os erros que citei persistem.